# Clarification on split tangents and vertex count

Tags: 3d, unity-game-engine, mesh, vertex

I know that **uv seams**, **tangent splitting**, **hard edge** etc. in an editor modeling tool cause the affected vertices to be splitted when imported in the engine.

Anyway, it's still doesn't completely clear to me what `split tangents` checkbox in `fbx import settings` do.
I have 2 question:

1. Why `Unity` let you choose to split or not? I mean, if for example I let `Unity` calculate the tangents on a model with an hard edge, doesn't the tangent splitting need to be done by default? It doesn't make much sense to me split a vertex because of 2 different normals and keep the calculated tangents the same, but maybe I'm missing something.
2. In any case, selecting `split tangent` checkbox should(eventually) increase vertex count, doesn't it? (even accordingly to this [post](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/import-model-settings-splitting-tangents.261233/)). But when I enable `split tangents`, the vertex count in the inspector decrease instead. Is it a bug or am I misunderstanding it?